# (Predicate<? super String> s) or (String s)

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a `TreeSet` of Strings (hardcoded).
Want to check that a given parameter String eg. "Person" if present in the TreeSet then return `true` otherwise return `false`.

Here I am confused by the Eclipse message regarding
`(Predicate<? super String> s)` vs `(String s)`:

> The method anyMatch(Predicate) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Please guide.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class SystemLabelValidator {

    public static boolean ValidateSystemLabel( String s) {  

        String j = s;

        boolean b = false;

        Set <String> SystemLabels = new TreeSet<String>();
        // Unique Strings
        SystemLabels.add("Person");
        SystemLabels.add("Player");
        SystemLabels.add("Hospital");
        SystemLabels.add("Nurse");
        SystemLabels.add("Room");

        System.out.println("\n==> Loop here.");
        for (String temp : SystemLabels) {
            System.out.println(temp);

            if(SystemLabels.stream().anyMatch(j)) {
                System.out.println("I need to return Boolean");
            }
            return b;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here I am confused by the Eclipse message regarding ((Predicate s) or (String s)": what message?

Comment: @azurefrog `? super String` can make a lot of sense, e.g. it would allow to pass a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

Comment: @ernest_k   The method anyMatch(Predicate<? super String>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)  If I use String as a Parameter than at Streaming I'm getting this Eclipse Message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to use a *Predicate* here. In order to check if the *String* is present in your `TreeSet` just use :

```
return systemLabels.contains("Person");
```

---

If you still insist on using *anyMatch* then you can do :

```
public static boolean validateSystemLabel(String s) {
    return systemLabels.stream().anyMatch(i -> i.equals(s));
}
```

Remember, a *predicate* expression needs to evaluate to a *boolean* value but in the code, you are passing in a *String* hence the compilation error.

Comment: The first one serves the Purpose.  which one is more efficient solution among two?

Comment: IMO, the first solution as there is no need for streams here.

Comment: @Optimight Considering using `TreeSet` as in your code, the worst case lookup time using `contains` would be `O(logn`) on the other hand if you use the stream solution, you might just have to iterate through all the elements in the collection meaning an `O(n)` runtime. Also, note that if you were to just use an unordered set such as `HashSet` the complexity might just be `O(1)` instead for a hashcode comparison and lookup into the hashmap which backs it up.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your solution is this line:

```
SystemLabels.stream().anyMatch(j);
```

Basically [anyMatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) expects `Predicate` as input not `String`.

But your problem has simpler solution:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SystemLabelValidator {

    private static final Set<String> SYSTEM_LABLES = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList("Person", "Player", "Hospital", "Nurse", "Room"));

    public static boolean validateSystemLabel( String value) {  
        return SYSTEM_LABLES.contains(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `anyMatch` is

```
boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
```

In your case, the argument must be a `Predicate<? super String>`. That is, a method which can take a string and return a boolean. This method is looking for one of the following

```
Predicate<String> (e.g. String::isEmpty)
Predicate<Object> (e.g. Objects::isNull)
Predicate<CharSequence>
Predicate<Comparable<String>>
Predicate<Serializable>
```

You have attempted to give it a string, which does not match the signature. One way to fix this would be:

```
if(SystemLabels.stream().anyMatch(j::equals)) {
    System.out.println("I need to return Boolean");
}
```